# Ghc: could not execute: hsx2hs

Tags: haskell

Изучаю Haskell и Happstack.
Установил HSX с помощью команды `cabal install happstack-hsp -j`.
Сделал по [инструкции](http://www.happstack.com/docs/crashcourse/index.html#hsx2hs).

При запуске компилятор выдает ошибку:

```
ghc: could not execute: hsx2hs
```

Гугление ни к чему не привело :(

**Обновление**

Пробую установить

```
cabal install hsx2hs
```

Выдает:

> Resolving dependencies... All the
> requested packages are already
> installed: hsx2hs-0.13.2 Use
> --reinstall if you want to reinstall anyway.

Comment: При запуске чего компилятор выдает ошибку? Установлен ли у вас `hsx2hs`? Путь к установке cabal'a прописан в PATH? Windows или Linux? Разные ссылки: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540096/cant-install-happstack-hsp), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21792441/how-to-reset-haskell-package-cache), [3](http://www.happstack.com/ircBot/irc-log/happs-2013-09-23.txt).

Comment: Пробую установить
cabal install hsx2hs

Выдает:
Resolving dependencies...
All the requested packages are already installed:
hsx2hs-0.13.2
Use --reinstall if you want to reinstall anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил проблему путем добавления /Users/User/Library/Haskell/bin в PATH